# Hide and show values from ngFor

Tags: angular, ionic2

I need to show and hide an element in a list. The list gets populated by using `*ngFor`.

I need to change those icons. I would get a `Boolean` value from `*ngFor`
by using `{{item.check}}`. I should not use ts file. I need this modification to occur in .html file .

```
 <ion-grid>
        <ion-row *ngFor="let item of dailyDays"> 
            <ion-col>
                <ion-icon show={{item.check}} name="checkmark"></ion-icon>
                <ion-icon show={{item.check}} name="close"></ion-icon>
            </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
</ion-grid>
```

Could someone help me to show and hide these item by using `Boolean` values from `{{item.check}}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `[attr.name]` attribute(property binding)

```
<ion-icon [attr.name]="item.check ? 'checkmark': 'close'"></ion-icon>
```

Comment: check my answer please

Comment: @YokeshVaradhan It seems good, but by using mine you could have single element,just toggle `ion-icon` element `name` attribute

Comment: @PankajParkar Is this ternary condition ??

Comment: @AbdElrahmanTelb yes, I mistyped.. corrected answer.. thanks for heads up

Comment: [attr.name] refers to what  i copy pasted the above but nothing is visiable over there

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me Will this work at all time

```
<ion-grid>
        <ion-row *ngFor="let item of dailyDays"> 
            <ion-col>
                <ion-icon [hidden]="item.check" name="checkmark"></ion-icon>
                <ion-icon  [hidden]="item.check" name="close"></ion-icon>
            </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
    </ion-grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

did you try also `ngIf`

```
<ion-col>
                <ion-icon *ngIf="item.check" name="checkmark"></ion-icon>
                <ion-icon  *ngIf="!item.check" name="close"></ion-icon>
            </ion-col>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should make use of [ngSwitch](https://angular.io/api/common/NgSwitch)

Editing your code as follows should work.

```
<ion-grid>
    <ion-row *ngFor="let item of dailyDays"> 
        <ion-col [ngSwitch]="item.check">
            <ion-icon *ngSwitchCase="true" name="checkmark"></ion-icon>
            <ion-icon *ngSwitchCase="false" name="close"></ion-icon>
        </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
</ion-grid>
```

Also you can add *ngSwitchDefault instead of case for the default icon

import the ngSwitch module in the ts file using below code:

```
import { NgSwitch } from @angular/common;
```

Answer (score 0):

If 'name' is an Angular [Input](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction%22Input%22) property for ion-icon component, then you can go with:

```html
<ion-col>
  <ion-icon [name]="item.check ? 'checkmark' : 'close'"></ion-icon>
</ion-col>
```

If it's a usual HTML attribute, you can do this:

```html
<ion-col>
  <ion-icon name="{{ item.check ? 'checkmark' : 'close' }}"></ion-icon>
</ion-col>
```

To avoid repeating the tag twice, as if for ngIf or ngSwitch